# No FileSystem for scheme: s3d

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I am trying to deploy a file on IBM Cloud Object Storage with Spark, but always when I try to call the saveAsTextFile method I am getting the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3d
```

My code looks like this (just for testing purposes):

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3d.service.endpoint", endPoint)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3d.service.access.key", accessKey)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3d.service.secret.key", secretKey)

val warehouseLocation = "file:${system:user.dir}/spark-warehouse"
val spark = SparkSession
.builder()
.appName("Test")
.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
.getOrCreate()

val file = sc.textFile("src/main/resources/test.csv").map(line => line.split(","))
file.saveAsTextFile("s3d://rollup.service/result")
```

Can you guys help me?
Thank you!

Comment: You should put your configurations into SparkSession, then get the context from that. SQLContext is deprecated in Spark2. What documentation are you referring to? For example, this isn't using s3d https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/AnalyticsforApacheSpark/cloud_object_storage.html#using-ibm-cloud-object-storage

Comment: I am referring to this documentation: https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/accessing-ibm-cloud-object-storage-from-spark-as-a-service/ (I know its kinda old but the only one I found with Spark).

What should I use instead of SQLContext? With just getting the context after my configurations its still not working...